# Angular 13 Unit Test Mock ngRxStore Subscribe And dispatch method

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, ngrx

Hello im working on Angular 13 and ngRxStore , my code works fine but my Unit Test not working properly , this is my code :

```
  myState: UserState | null = null;
  
  constructor(private store: Store<any>) { }
  
  getUserData(){
      
      this.store.dispatch(new SearchAction(new SearchCriteria(seachTerm)));

      this.store.subscribe(state => {

        this.myState = state.userState;

        if (this.myState?.dataState == MyEnum.LOADED) {

          if (this.myState.user != null) {

            this.myforM.patchValue({
              username: this.myState.user.username
            });

          }
        }

      });  
  }
```

and this is my Unit test that trigger Exception :

```
fdescribe('MyComponent', () => {
    
const userDtoMock: UserDTO = {
    'username': 'myusername',
    'email': 'test',
    'adress': 'adress'
  }

  const expectedState: UserState = {
    user: userDtoMock,
    errorMessage: '',
    dataState: MyEnum.LOADED
  };

  let storeMock = {
      userState: expectedState
  };

  const testStore = of(storeMock);
  
  beforeEach(async () => {

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        // imports...
      providers: [
        // providers...
        {
          provide: Store,
          useValue: testStore
        },
      ],
      declarations: [
       //..components
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });
  
   it('#getUserData', () => {

    //Given

    var mockStore = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Store);
    const storeSpy = spyOn(mockStore, 'dispatch').and.callThrough();

    //When
    component.getUserData();

    //Then
    expect(storeSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

  });
}
```

And this is the error during the test :

```
     Error: <spyOn> : dispatch() method does not exist
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
Error: <spyOn> : dispatch() method does not exist
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
    at <Jasmine>
```

To correct this Test i removed this provider :

```
{
  provide: Store,
  useValue: testStore
}
```

but in this case my store.subscribe is not covered in my test.

do you have any idea how i can mock store dispatch method And My Store Data Object  ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at this resource: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing? You can even do `integration testing`, that would be the most complete.

Comment: @AliF50 thanks a lot i found the solution in the page you sent. Regards

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution in this page https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing.
so this is the modification in my unit test :
i added a mock provider : `provideMockStore({ initialState: storeMock })`
in the providers section and i used a MockStore object like this :

```
let store: MockStore;
```

in the `beforeEach` method i inject it  :

```
store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
```

and this is how i spy on my store object to call dispatch method :

```
spyOn(store, 'dispatch');
```

i hope it was helpful.